# How to group many files by size and by month using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with many types of files (.svg, .png, etc), the date when it was created (cteated_at) and its size in bytes (size).
I can make the sum for each type of file BUT not by month. 
How can I group the size of each file by month?

```
#this is the dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file_type': ['file.svg'] * 1 +  ['file.png'] * 2 +  ['file.csv'] * 2,
    'size': [11] * 5,
    'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] *1 + ['2020-02-01 23:00:34'] * 2 + ['2020-03-01 23:00:34']*1 + ['2020-01-02 23:00:34']})

#this where modify the dataframe
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.normalize()
df=df.set_index('created_at')


#this is where I make the sum

(df_1['size'].groupby(df_1.file_name.str.lower().str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False)
           .fillna('unknown'))
           .sum().sort_values(ascending=[False]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution was pretty close, we also need to groupby `dt.strftime` of your datetime column:

```
# df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
group1= df['file_type'].str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False)
group2 = df['created_at'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').rename('created_at_month')

df.groupby([group1, group2])['size'].sum().reset_index()

  file_type created_at_month  size
0      .csv          2020-01    11
1      .csv          2020-03    11
2      .png          2020-02    22
3      .svg          2020-01    11
```

---

Or if you dont want month numbers but names, we can use `dt.month_name`:

```
group1= df['file_type'].str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False)
group2 = df['created_at'].dt.month_name().rename('created_at_month')

df.groupby([group1, group2])['size'].sum().reset_index()

  file_type created_at_month  size
0      .csv          January    11
1      .csv            March    11
2      .png         February    22
3      .svg          January    11
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the year? Because I will plot this.